# document is not defined, react ssr

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I am using react and doing server-side rendering using node but when I run my server.js file, I get this error that the document is not defined. Here I know that in node document does not exist like on the browser, what should I do to solve this error ?

THIS IS MY WEBPACK.SERVER.JS FILE

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
module.exports = {
    entry: './server/index.js',
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    output: {
      path: path.resolve('server-build'),
      filename: '[name].js',
      chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js'

},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '*']
},
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            vendor: {
                test: /node_modules/,
                name: 'vendor',
                chunks: 'initial',
                enforce: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

THIS IS THE ERROR I AM GETTING

[nodemon] starting `node ./server-build/main.js`
webpack://frontend/./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertStyleElement.js?:5

var element = document.createElement("style");
^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object.insertStyleElement (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertStyleElement.js?:5:17)
at Object.domAPI (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js?:59:30)
at addElementStyle (webpack://frontend/./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

1. Move the code to the client, if you want to change the DOM elements. Because document relates to the DOM (Document Object Model) in a web browser.
2. Use an external library like [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom).
3. Use something like [browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify) to include Node.js modules in your client-side code (not recommended in you case).